# How to delete dumpstate/logcat on Moto E

Tags: insufficient-memory, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-e

My phone is running out of internal memory. So I searched online and found a solution, which was to dial *#9900# and then delete dumpstate/logcat. But when I dial the same on my MOTO E, I dont see anything happening. It Just says USSD Code running and closes. My phone is running on Lollipop 5.1. Can you please help me delete dumpstate/logcat?

Answer (score 3):

You are running an USSD(SIM specific) code. Once you enter the last character of an [MMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMI) code(usually a pound or hash(#) symbol) your phones parses the code and open the menu for you automatically.

Dumpstate, logcat files are stored on the `/data/log` partition that, unless you root the phone, you and none of the apps you install will have access to it.

Dialing `*#9900#` and selecting `Delete dumpstate/logcat` clears the logs even if your phone is not rooted and this seems to work only on some Samsung Phones. So that excludes the Motorola phones.
<sup>(based on the [comments from this blog post](http://tripoverit.blogspot.in/2013/09/fix-for-android-phones-running-low-on.html))</sup>

**Note**: *If you enter the MMI code in the dialer app your phone's MMI parser will automatically open the secret menu after typing the last character of the code. If the MMI parser of you phone doesn't recognize the code, then it will not work in your phone and pressing the dial button after entering the code will run USSD code to your network provider*

You can try using [adb commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to see if you can get help clearing logcats of you phone. The following command clears/flushes the entire log and exits.

```
adb logcat -c
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

But before trying all these things you need to see the frequent questions under the [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) tag and its [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for what to do when your phone storage is almost full.

Comment: `adb logcat -c` does not clear any log files on disk.

Comment: not useful for me